# Replacing gas range in an old house with copper propane (LP) gas line

Tags: gas, installation, range, propane, copper

I'm facing a dilemma of replacing a gas range in a relatively old (30 years) house that is using LP gas (external tanks). The gas lines are copper and haven't changed since the original construction. Today, the range installer told me that they are not allowed to connect ranges to copper gas lines.

Question: what is the current strategy for issues like this (I'm also planning to replace a gas dryer later and I assume it will be the same scenario). Would it be sufficient to attach flexible kit like [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0972P33TH) to the copper line before the installer can connect the appliance? Am I supposed to replace the whole copper line infrastructure with *whatever-is-the-current-code*? Is it something else?

Comment: I haven't kept up, but I believe CSST is the common "modern" gas line of choice these days. Perhaps contact your propane supplier, who would know better...

Comment: Is that "not allowed" range-installer-policy, some weird local Code amendment, or are they claiming that the model Codes prohibit them from hooking up to a copper LP line?

Comment: Do you currently have a coil of copper tubing behind your range and dryer?

Comment: You will need to see/ask about the local regulations about gas lines.  I can see them not connecting directly to relativity ridged copper pipe to a movable device, but there might be other regulations.